# Crawling data faster in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm crawling data of 25GB of bz2 files. Right now I'm processing the zip file, open it, get the data of the sensors, get the median, then after I finish processing all the files, write them to excel file. It takes a full day to process those files, which is not bearable.

I want to make the process faster, so I want to fire as many threads, but how would I approach that problem ? A Pseudo code of the idea would be good.

The problem that I'm thinking of is I have time stamps for each day of the zip file.
So for example I have day1 at 20:00, I need to process it's file then save it in a list, while other threads can process other days, but I need to sync the data to be in sequence in the written file in disk.

Basically I want to accelerate it faster.

Here is a pseudo code of the process file as shown by the answer

```
def proc_file(directoary_names):
    i = 0

    try:

        for idx in range(len(directoary_names)):
            print(directoary_names[idx])
            process_data(directoary_names[idx], i, directoary_names)
            i = i + 1
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
       pass

    print("writing data")
    general_pd['TimeStamp'] = timeStamps
    general_pd['S_strain_HOY'] = pd.Series(S1)
    general_pd['S_strain_HMY'] = pd.Series(S2)
    general_pd['S_strain_HUY'] = pd.Series(S3)
    general_pd['S_strain_ROX'] = pd.Series(S4)
    general_pd['S_strain_LOX'] = pd.Series(S5)
    general_pd['S_strain_LMX'] = pd.Series(S6)
    general_pd['S_strain_LUX'] = pd.Series(S7)
    general_pd['S_strain_VOY'] = pd.Series(S8)
    general_pd['S_temp_HOY'] = pd.Series(T1)
    general_pd['S_temp_HMY'] = pd.Series(T2)
    general_pd['S_temp_HUY'] = pd.Series(T3)
    general_pd['S_temp_LOX'] = pd.Series(T4)
    general_pd['S_temp_LMX'] = pd.Series(T5)
    general_pd['S_temp_LUX'] = pd.Series(T6)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'c:\ahmed\median_data_meter_12.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    # Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
    general_pd.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    # Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
    writer.save()
```

Sx to Tx are sesnor values..

Comment: Why are you duplicating code? Replace everything in the 'except' block with a 'pass'. Open the zip files directly with gzip.open() will save you a lot of time

Comment: sorry I'm beginner in python

Comment: We all started somewhere... :)

Comment: In python - multithread splits a single process in separate threads, multiprocessing runs separate processes (which can be on different CPU's). rule of thumb is to multi-thread tasks that do a lot of waiting and mutliprocess tasks that would benefit from more CPU's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `multiprocessing`, it seem you have a pretty straightforward task.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

manager = Manager()
l = manager.list()

def proc_file(file):
    # Process it
    l.append(median)

p = Pool(4) # however many process you want to spawn
p.map(proc_file, your_file_list)

# somehow save l to excel.
```

Update: Since you want to keep the file names, perhaps as a pandas column, here's how:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

manager = Manager()
d = manager.dict()

def proc_file(file):
    # Process it
    d[file] = median # assuming file given as string. if your median (or whatever you want) is a list, this works as well.

p = Pool(4) # however many process you want to spawn
p.map(proc_file, your_file_list)

s = pd.Series(d)
# if your 'median' is a list
# s = pd.DataFrame(d).T
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path)
s.to_excel(writer, 'sheet1')
writer.save() # to excel format.
```

If each of your file will produce multiple values, you can create a dictionary where each element is a list that contains those values

Comment: how would I synchronize the data for examples multiple processes will have different lists of different time stamps.. how would I make them work in order ?

Comment: please look at the modified post

Comment: hold on .. you can use a `dict` instead of list if that's the case.

Comment: yes, but I still don't know how to crawl over the files in different processes, please look at my snippet code

Comment: Each process should just be by itself - taking *one* file. Your pool of process will take care of iterating over the files.

Comment: Sx to Tx are global list variables.. general_pd is the general data frame that is saved to excel file from all the lists of sensors and temperature

Comment: I got it, but I still don't know how to group the reterieved data from Sx to Tx into one general file that should be saved into desk...

Comment: I'm a little confused after reading your snippet... but if I'm getting it correctly, you're creating a bunch of list, in multiprocessing case, *each* of those list would be a global `manager.dict`. with file name since you want to keep order intact. You would then be able to `merge` those dictionary on the key and turn the resulting dictionary to pandas dataframe.

Comment: Yes, I want to merge all those lists into one ordered dictionary to be able to save it

Comment: Now I think a better way would be puttting *all* of your values created under each file to a `list` and then put it into a dictionary like my snippet above. So instead of putting `median` to each entry, putting a `list` that contains all you need.

Comment: If I declare the dictionary of the manager as global I get an exception

Comment: you shouldn't need to declare it as global. it will auto register as global when you declare it on the file scope. Also, I can't access that website for my reason, if you have any questions, you probably also want to consult docs 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: I wanna  test the writing to the file if it's written correctly or no, I close the program by ctrl+c but it doesn't save the file after closing it's process. Does your snippet merge the data from all Lists ?

Comment: Of course it doesn’t, you’ll have to wait for the multiprocessing to finish before the file can show up

Comment: I defined the manager and the dictionary inside main, and as you said the dictionary should be global, when I use inside the function process_data, it's not defined.

Comment: I'm using windows by the way, so its not possible to declare the manager as global

Comment: so the problem how to get the dictionary from the manager into process_file function

Comment: `inside main` don't do that.

Comment: If I declare it outside main, it gives me exception freezeprocess problem

Comment: An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.